# Best practice for a global config

Tags: c++, openmp, config, yaml-cpp

I have several c++ programs that are all reading a YAML configuration file in `/etc/foo/config.yml`. I have written a function that reads the config from the file

```
YAML::Node load_config();
```

(using the `yaml-cpp` library).

I would like this configuration to be loaded once, at the beginning of the `main()` function of my program, and then **accessible everywhere** as some kind of global variable.

Currently, many of my functions have **extra** parameters that are just values read from the configuration file. It could be avoided by having this global configuration, making my function definitions and calls much simpler and readable.

*Side note: I am also using OpenMP for distributing computation, which means that the configuration must be accessible to all parallel processes.*

Could someone give a tiny example of what this would look like when done the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not giving enough constrains on what the "right way" is. You would at least need to provide some usage examples and some criteria to judge proposals by. Also it is not clear to me what `OpenMP` has to do with anything. Are you talking about loading settings in a single program or synchronizing changes across distributed systems?

Comment: @nwp Thank you for your comment. I feel like what I am trying to do (having a configuration available everywhere within the program) is a pretty common problem some people must have already solved. I don't have any other constraint. The reason why I noted the fact that I am using OpenMP is that I wanted to make sure the solution would allow the configuration to be shared between processes. I don't really know if it has to do with anything. I am just talking about loading settings from a file at the start of the program, that's it. Thanks again.

Comment: You might look at singleton pattern, but think twice before use it. extra parameter allow to ease the test, have clearer dependencies ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's one way. It's a variation on the idea of the schwartz counter to manage a global singleton (for example, `std::cout` itself)

```
// globals.hpp
#include <istream>

struct globals_object
{
    globals_object()
    {
        // record number of source files which instanciate a globals_object
        ++init_count_;
    }

    ~globals_object()
    {
        // The last source file cleans up at program exit
        if(--init_count_ == 0)
        {
            if (pimpl_)
            {
                delete pimpl_;
            }
        }
    }

    // internal implementation   
    struct impl
    {
        void load(std::istream& is)
        {
            // do loading code here
        }

        int get_param_a() const {
            return a_;
        }

        int a_;
    };

    // (re)load global state    
    void load(std::istream&& is)
    {
        if (pimpl_) delete pimpl_;
        pimpl_ = new impl;
        pimpl_->load(is);
    }

    // public parameter accessor    
    int get_param_a() const {
        return get_impl().get_param_a();
    }

private:    
    static int init_count_;
    static impl* pimpl_;
    static impl& get_impl()
    {
        return *pimpl_;
    }
};
// one of these per translation unit
static globals_object globals;


// globals.cpp

// note - not initialised - will be zero-initialised
// before global constructors are called 
// you need one of these in a cpp file
int globals_object::init_count_;
globals_object::impl* globals_object::pimpl_;


// main file

// #include "globals.hpp"
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    globals.load(std::ifstream("settings.yml"));

}


// any other file

// #include "globals.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << globals.get_param_a() << std::endl;
}
```